# MDT and VC++ 2010 Silent Installing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, mdt-2012, mdt

For 32bit and 64bit I am using the following commandline:

```
vcredist_2010_x64.exe /q:a /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /l*v %temp%\vcredist_x86.log"
```

The application will install, but it requires me to manually accept the terms on both 32/64bit versions. Is there a way to get the application to accept via commandline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding /quiet as a parameter to the command line.

EDIT: vcredist_2010_x64.exe /q:a /c:"msiexec /i vcredist.msi /qn /quiet /l*v %temp%\vcredist_x86.log"